# Get Kafka heartbeat status in C# application

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, heartbeat

I've a C# application which uses `Confluent.Kafka`. I can see that the `ConsumerConfig` has a `HeartbeatIntervalMs` method which sets the heartbeat interval. The `ConsumerConfig` is then used in a `ConsumerBuilder` call. I can't see anywhere that the heartbeat is applied though. Is there any way I can get some sort of heartbeat status?

Comment: Did you check this link - https://chrzaszcz.dev/2019/06/kafka-heartbeat-thread/? Maybe it could give some insights for this topic.

Comment: Yes, been following that but as the examples use Kotlin(I think) I'm trying to interpret what it's telling me. Just don't fully understand it yet.